# How to update Oracle BPMN flow diagram during execution

Tags: oracle, bpmn

I'm working with Oracle BPMN (Fusion middleware), using JDeveloper to create BPMN processes, and writing Java code for a custom page to display the flow diagram for running processes. The problem being encountered is that the BPMN diagrams do not display/update until they hit certain trigger events (apparently asynchronous event points). So in many cases the diagrams do not even show up in a query until the BPMN process completes. Note we don't normally have user input tasks, which qualify as async events and also result in the diagram then showing up.

Our team has talked to Oracle about it and their solution was to wrap every BPMN call (mostly service calls) in asynchronous BPEL wrappers, so that the BPMN calls an async request/response (thus as two actions) that calls the service. Doing this does work, but it adds a huge overhead to the effort of developing BPMN processes, because every action has to be wrapped.

So I'm wondering if anyone else has explored or potentially solved this problem.

Some code snippets of what we're doing (partial code only):

To get the running instance IDs:

```
List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<Column>();
columns.add(...); // repeated for all relevant fields
Ordering ...
Predicate ...
IInstanceQueryInput input = new IInstanceQueryInput();
List<IProcessInstance> instances = client.getInstanceQueryService().queryProcessInstances(context, columns, predicate, ordering, input);
// however, instances doesn't return the instance until the first async event, or until completion
```

After that the AuditProcessDiagrammer is used to get the flow diagram, and DiagramEvents uesd to update / highlight the flow in progress. The instanceId does show up in the Oracle fusion control panel, so it must at least potentially be available. But trying to get an image for it results in a null image:

```
IProcessInstance pi = client.getInstanceQueryService().getProcessInstance(context, instance);
// HERE --> pi is null until the image is available (so the rest of this isn't run)
String compositeDn = pi.getSca().getCompositeDN();
String componentName = pi.getSca().getComponentName();
IProcessModelPackage package = client.getProcessModelService().getProcessModel(context, compositeDn, componentName);
ProcessDiagramInfo info = new ProcessDiagramInfo();
info.setModelPackage(package);
AuditProcessDiagrammer dg = new AuditProcessDiagrammer(info.getModelPackage().getProcessModel().getProcess());
List<IAuditInstance> audits = client.getInstanceQueryService().queryAuditInstanceByProcessId(context, instance);
List<IDiagramEvent> events = // function to get these
dg.highlight(events);
String base64image = dg.getImage();
```

See the HERE --> part. That's where I need instance to be valid.

If there are good alternatives (setting, config, etc...) that others have successfully used, I'd love to hear it. I'm really not interested in strange workarounds (already have that in the BPEL wrapper). I'm looking for a solution that allows the BPMN process flow to remain simple. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about BPMN, but according to documentation ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/integration.1111/e10226/bpmn_config.htm#autoId1 ) Fusion Control Panel integrated with BPMN process with help of `TEMPLATE_BI_Partition_Composite_Process` object. If process displayed on Control Panel as you described, and it's possible to access this object directly, I think you can get list of instances same as in Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks. However, that's referencing the deployed composite as a runnable entity, not a specific running instance (which is what I'm looking for).

Comment: Citation: "The SOA composite instance contains an instance of each of the components defined in the SOA composite. For example, if your SOA composite defines a BPMN process and a human Task, then the SOA composite instance contains a BPMN process instance and a human task instance." from this doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/doc.1111/e15176/soa_composite_bpmpd.htm#CHDGJJEH

Comment: So, from my point of view (may be wrong) `TEMPLATE_BI_Partition_Composite_Process`  must contain a list of composite  instances and each of composite instance must include a  concrete process instance.

Comment: I think this is a case of overloaded terms ("instance"). The documents you're referencing a for defining the BPMN process instance (which is more like a class definition) and I need running instances (runtime objects). They are separate. It seems (from other data that shows up) that it ought to be possible to get to the data runtime, but the Java API doesn't appear to properly expose it. I'm looking for ways that the Java API might expose that.